# swift self.presentViewController fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, crash, xcode6, presentviewcontroller

I want to go to another screen base on the decision make on a custom cell (delegate method). I am not sure why i am receiving this error message as i manage to pass this code in another another storyboard(call it storyboard C). I need guidance on how to debug such problem. Kindly help :D

In this class i init the delegate upon buttonAction

```
class ImageValueCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

var delegate: ImagesOperationDelegate = ResultViewController()


    @IBAction func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!){

    if(myMachine.oldImageList.count > 0){
        delegate.displayOldImages!(myMachine)
    }else{
        delegate.displayLatestImages!(myMachine)
    }
}
```

This is the delegate method

```
//THIS IS IN STORYBOARD A
class ResultViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, ImagesOperationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var examinationTable: UITableView!


    //Delegate Method
    func displayInformationA(){

    //DESTINATION STORYBOARD
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainViewController") as UIViewController

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) //CRASH AT THIS LINE

    }



}
```

This is the log after `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)`
[image]

This is the log after `let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainViewController") as UIViewController`

[image]
[image]

And i get this `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` after `self.presentViewController`

EDIT1: Somehow my `self` is null after going into the delegate method `func displayInformationA` 
[image]

Comment: Please show more code.

Comment: @gabbler more codes posted. Thanks for reply

Comment: `displayOldImages` is similar with `displayInformationA`? Both of them are functions in  ResultViewController?

Comment: @gabbler yes you are correct.

Comment: `var delegate: ImagesOperationDelegate = ResultViewController()` this create a new `ResultViewController`, which is not necessarily the `ResultViewController` you get from storyboard, without seeing more of your code, this is my guess. You can put a project here, so people can get the whole idea and the problem will be fixed much quicker.